# How can we override a default fl specific field through a query

Tags: solr, lucene

In my schema i am having 20 fields.

I am having a qt in which

```
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="fl">f1,f2,f3,f4</str>
  ...
</lst>
```

On some specific condition, I want to use aliases in solr query such that
When(condition)
f2 name should be replaced by field2
but when i m using it through solr query like
fl=field2:f2 then only field2 is printed in json response.
I want all fields of fl in default qt to printed in the json response
that is 
f1
field2
f3
f4
Please tell how can i achieve this because if i write in solr query
fl=field2:f2,*, then it will print all fields of schema which i don't want. I only want qt fl fields in json reponse.

Comment: Qt is the parameter for request handler, how it’s related to your problem?

Comment: in Qt, I have defined fl. Now while using that qt through http request i want to rename or use aliases for one of the field mentioned in fl.

Comment: Could you share your solrconfig part with that request handler? You could override fl in via dynamic request. Will it be helpful

Comment: It may help if you provide us with an example query url showing your use of fl and qt (qt sounds strange in this context, as @Mysterion already remarks. Do you actually mean q?